# Ajax Sys.WebForms.PageRequestManagerServerErrorException

Tags: asp.net, ajax, iis, ajaxcontroltoolkit

A little background. I have a IIS8 server. Lets call this server ABC. 
In server ABC. I have two website. One is called websiteA and websiteB. they are identical website. Only subtle differences since websiteB is primary used for test and dev purpose.

Can you please help me to troubleshoot the issue on WebsiteA?
The error is a generic error:

```
Sys.WebForms.PageRequestManagerServerErrorException: An unknown error occurred while processing the request on the server. The status code returned from the server was: 500
```

This error does not happen in WebsiteB. and I have compared the ASPX page to make sure they are exactly the same.

Can you help me how to troubleshoot the error 500 on the server? I don't know how...

This is the register Assembly for the ajax on top of the ASPX page:

```
<%@ Register Assembly="AjaxControlToolkit" Namespace="AjaxControlToolkit" TagPrefix="asp" %>
```

This is the snippet for my toolkit

```
<asp:ToolkitScriptManager ID="ToolkitScriptManager1" runat="server" EnablePageMethods="True"></asp:ToolkitScriptManager>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Wow. I fixed this. So for kicks I start removing stuff from the page. 
The first one I remove was this bit. because in less than 1 year ago I added this bit.

```
         <asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel1" runat="server">
                <ContentTemplate>
                </ContentTemplate>
            </asp:UpdatePanel>
```

Then I get a different error message: 
I get this error now:

```
System.Web.HttpException: Maximum request length exceeded
```

Did some google of that error and boom! I get this stackoverflow link:
[Maximum request length exceeded](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3853767/maximum-request-length-exceeded). I follow the suggestion and my problem goes away! Horray

and the solution is to add this in my web.config!
(the one in bold is the new stuff I added)

**System.webserver** is the new bit

and

**executionTimeout="100000" maxRequestLength="214748364"**

```
<configuration>
  <system.web>
    <compilation debug="true" strict="false" explicit="true" targetFramework="4.5" />
    <httpRuntime targetFramework="4.5" executionTimeout="100000" maxRequestLength="214748364"  />
    <customErrors mode="Off"/>
  </system.web>
  <system.webServer>
    <security>
      <requestFiltering>
        <requestLimits maxAllowedContentLength="1073741824" />
      </requestFiltering>
    </security>
  </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```